# Filter DatetimeIndex vector to a certain frequency with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I'm using [findatapy](https://github.com/cuemacro/findatapy) to acquire FX Rates from DukasCopy, the package works great. This is the script I'm using:

```
from findatapy.market import Market, MarketDataRequest, MarketDataGenerator

market = Market(market_data_generator=MarketDataGenerator())

md_request = MarketDataRequest(start_date='01 Feb 2017', finish_date='03 Feb 2017', category='fx', fields=['bid', 'ask'], freq='tick', data_source='dukascopy', tickers=['EURUSD'])

df = market.fetch_market(md_request)

print(df)
print(len(df))
print(df.index)
print(len(df.index))
```

I'm only interested in the points that have an hourly frequency (00:00:00, 01:00:00, 02:00:00 and so on). This means that after filtering, I should only get 24 points per day.

Now, what I get as an outcome, is this.

df:

[image]

df.index:

[image]

What I'd like to do now, but I'm completely clueless about how to it, is to filter the index using an hourly frequency and then select the corresponding points.

I think that what I should do is to create an array with Pandas that has the desired index and use that to slice my main array, but how can I do that? Can pandas.date_range help me create this 'desired' array? Or is there a much simpler way of doing this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ this worked great :), this was the outcome I was looking for. I'd also like to split the index vector (which is my 'Date' vector), but I'll try to find my way to it because it seems 'easier'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you explain how you want it split? I'm not clear on that bit.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ if you see the outcome for 'df.index' only, you'll see the day+blankspace+hour. I'd like to split that into 'Day' and 'Hour', separately.

Comment: `d = df.index.day; h = df.index.hour?`

Comment: This worked :), thanks again @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I don't know how I didn't find these commads before. But I'm really glad you helped me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `pd.TimeGrouper` object and extract the first row for each hour group, something like this:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1H')).head(1)
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED thank you again, I'll take the second line because I noticed that df.resample('1H').mean() computes a mean of the values between an interval and that's not what I want. I want just the time that's closest to each hour, which is what I get by using df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1H')).head(1)

Comment: @AquilesPáez Alright, no worries. I added both because I wasn't 100% sure what you wanted. Also, if you want to split the index, you can just do `d = df.index.day; h = df.index.hour`.